# How to use function 'LISTAGG' in Netteza

Tags: sql, sas

```
My data

B_STAFF_CODE         PERIOD_COLL
----------------------------------
1111111               201901
2222222               201901
1111111               201902
3333333               201903
----------------------------------
```

I have try to use the function 'LISTAGG' via SQL statement in Netteza
and I get the error as below,

**ERROR:  Function 'LISTAGG' is not an analytic aggregate but is called with a window spec**

```
SELECT B_STAFF_CODE,
       LISTAGG(PERIOD_COLL, ' , ') WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY PERIOD_COLL) as CONCAT_PERIOD
FROM F_STAFF_MASTER
GROUP BY B_STAFF_CODE;
```

```
B_STAFF_CODE         CONCAT_PERIOD
----------------------------------
1111111               201901, 201902
2222222               201901
3333333               201903
----------------------------------
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use [GROUP_CONCAT()](https://www.ibm.com/developerworks/community/wikis/home?lang=en#!/wiki/W9363c60167c7_4e4b_a188_a8bad09b7861/page/C__%20UDX%20Examples)

```
SELECT B_STAFF_CODE,
       GROUP_CONCAT(PERIOD_COLL, ' , ') as CONCAT_PERIOD
FROM F_STAFF_MASTER
GROUP BY B_STAFF_CODE
```

Comment: ERROR:  Function 'GROUP_CONCAT(NVARCHAR, UNKNOWN)' does not exist Unable to identify a function that 
       satisfies the given argument types You may need to add explicit typecasts